# How do I obtain a listing from an SQL table of price changes

Tags: sql, datetime, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I have a simple table that contains invoice detail data.  I need to run a query that returns the price change by for example

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a gaps and islands problem, where you to build groups of "adjacent" rows that have the same price.

I think the simplest approach here is to use the difference between row numbers to build the groups:

```
select itemno, state, price, min(rcv_date) frst_date, max(rcv_date) last_date
from (
    select t.*, 
        row_number() over(partition by item_no, state order by rcv_date) rn1,
        row_number() over(partition by item_no, state, price order by rcv_date) rn2
    from mytable t
) t
group by item_no, state, price, rn1 - rn2
```